# Shore based shark fishing

Tags: fishing, fishing-rods

So I have wanted to catch sharks like 7 gill in california and I have some questions about reels and rods. 
So I want to be able to cast my bait out to where the sharks are but most people seem to use a drone or keyak, but somebody on a fishing forum said they they casted from shore with a 9 foot pole. So I was wondering if I could actually cast from shore like that. I was looking at a rod blank called jawbone 2 xtreme sledgehammer that's 10 ft and 50-130 pound line. wandering if that or anything else like it? Also would a spinner or bait caster be better?

Comment: Related: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/24274/rods-for-shark-fishing (same user, similar questions)