# Rods for shark fishing

Tags: united-states, fishing, fishing-tackle, fishing-rods

I was looking at jawbone 2 xtreme blanks, the sledgehammer model is 10' with 100-250 pound line rating. It's E glass with 28-36 ounce lure rating. I've been looking all over the Internet for something like this but cannot find anything other than mud hole's gator glass witch is still to small. So does anyone know of a surf rod or blank in the 10 foot and up range that can handle big sharks like tiger, mako, and bull with very large lure weight rating? Also it has to be something I can get in california because the jawbone is store only pickup in texas

Comment: why don't you try [Noodling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noodling). Save yourself a few $